# Download Link of mp3 on Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-browser

I am trying to make a download link for mp3 on my website. The link is like this:

```
<a href="URL_TO_MP3" download="FILENAME.mp3">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

On all the others browsers, this link is ok. Only the Android browser doesn't function properly. The download begins and loads forever. No single extension is on the name of the download on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3) when I test it. It just writes the name of the file without its extension. My client uses just Android Browser...

How would I fix this?

EDIT : 
Yes, but the download ends never... The file is downloading but there isn't his extension, so the download ends never... Do you know what I can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't download it with a simple click. This is a "feature" of the browser.

You have to teach your user to Long press the link - it'll pop a menu, including "Save As" which will allow them to save it.